# How to remove borders around broken images in webkit?

Tags: html, css, webkit, html-email

Can anybody advise me on this? WebKit browsers keeps on putting a gray 1px border around disabled images. The reason I need this removed is for email optimization for when email clients have images disabled. Works fine in Firefox, but WebKit browsers keep showing the border.

I have tried `border:none !important` everywhere including inline, but Chrome/Safari are being stubborn.

Edit: Here is sample html with inline css

```
<img style="outline:none;text-decoration:none;display:block;border:none;-webkit-border:0;" border="0" src="images/rm_bnk.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="test" />
```

Comment: Do you mean something like: table, img {-webkit-border:0 !important;} ? Still not working.

Comment: can u show your code html or css

Comment: Sure, have added in original questions.

Comment: HI Kaizoku check to this http://tinkerbin.com/GyG8F7Di

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to remove it but I wrapped the image in an element that has overflow hidden property in its styles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Hide Broken Image border</title>
  <style>
    body{
      background-color:azure;
    }
    .image-container{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      overflow:hidden;
      display:block;
      background-color:orange; /*not necessary, just to show the image box, can be added to img*/
    }
    .image-container img{
      margin:-1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="image-container">
    <img src="path-to-image" alt="I'm Broken :(" width="102" height="102">
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Take a look at this bin
http://jsbin.com/OpAyAZa/1/edit

Comment: Nice one, let me test it across email clients

Answer (score 24):

Amit's answer is just great, but a small advice:
use **visibility: hidden;** instead of **display: none;**

```css
img:not([src]) {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

- so you could save img block size and positioning of other elements. its usefull in most cases, i use it on my sites with images *lazyload* and show just blank block before the image loads.

Comment: Thank you for this! This is the only thing that worked for me :)

Comment: This is a great solution when using lazy loading.

Answer (score 10):

If `img` `src` is not present or broken then use below `css` code

```
img:not([src]){ display:none; }
```

this css hide image till `img` `src` is not loaded completely.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we inline pseudo styles?

Answer (score 3):

Browsers don't seem to really give you a way to remove that border. Your simplest solution is to change your img to a div and apply the image as a background.

That way, if there's no src, you won't get the broken image icon and border.

Update: Microsoft Outlook makes things difficult, and the cure is almost worse than the disease: vector markup language, shape elements, imagedata elements, etc. If you google around you'll see how to use them http://blog.oxagile.com/2010/04/23/background-images-for-outlook-2007-and-outlook-2010-beta/

Outlook users might just have to go without the image so that you can call it a day.

Comment: Yeah have thought of this, but emails don't really like background images (outlook is the main culprit for this)

Comment: Cool, I will accept this for now, was hoping for some kind of css hack to override webkit default css.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some JavaScript to remove the broken image. Thats the only way

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var self  = images[i];
    self.onerror = function () {
        self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
    }
}
```

Because rendering of broken image varies from browser to browser and it could not be altered.

P.S: `onerror` will fire when the image is not loaded

Comment: Thanks, but this is for emails so javascript is not available.

Comment: then try hilsons solution. thats a better idea

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of `width` and `height`:

```css
.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Just had to replace it with `max-width` and `max-height`:

```css
.img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

So, in your case, remove:
`width="10" height="10"`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code to remove borders around broken images in webkit.

```
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var self  = images[i];
    self.onerror = function () {
        self.parentNode.removeChild(self);
    }
}
```