# Removing image borders

Tags: html, css

Am I going mad. I'm trying to remove the image border, but can't seem to shift it with this

HTML:

```
<img src="../_test.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Test">
```

CSS:

```
img {
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/szkuc/)

Comment: There is no border in your live example...

Comment: Is your image wrapped in an `<a>` tag by any chance?

Comment: This appears to be browser-specific. Chrome adds the border to unloadable images. FF (and perhaps others) do not show the border. To correct, make sure that your image URL is valid. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szkuc/4/)

Comment: _Am I going mad._ Yes... I believe so.

Comment: It looks like this is impossible to do with broken images:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151340/how-to-remove-borders-around-broken-images-in-webkit

Comment: I'm viewing it in Chrome Mac, and theres a image border

Comment: Add div tag instead of img tag and use background image -

Comment: @Rob, will you verify that the border goes away when you use a valid image? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szkuc/4/)

Answer (score 0):

[There are javascript solutions to handle broken images.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

[You could also wrap it in a div and do some tricks](http://jsfiddle.net/szkuc/16/) (this requires a space before your `alt` text to show, as the "border" is within the padding area of the img). **However, this is probably a bit excessive for just handling a broken image (*fix your image path instead*).**

**HTML**

```
<div class="brokenImgBorderKill">
  <img src="../_test.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=" Test">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
}

.brokenImgBorderKill {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.brokenImgBorderKill img {
    margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}
```